# How to put additional server libs to Tomcat(JBossEWS) on Openshift?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, openshift

I have a Tomcat/JBossEWS application on Openshift and would need to put some shared jars into lib directory - `jbossews/lib`. However this directory does not have permission to do this.

I do not use Git and deploy compiled war.

Where can I put shared libraries and how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GIT for this, as far as I know, there is no way around it.

Make a lib directory in your application and place your files there, use git to commit them. The procedure is described here: [openshift - tomcat dependencies](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your libs somewhere else, for example into app-root/data/lib, and then edit jbossews/conf/catalina.properties: append "${catalina.base}/../app-root/data/lib/*.jar" at the end of "common.loader" property